# Changing size of a JointGrid marginal plot or deleting it

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to completely get rid of the y-marginal plot of `seaborn.JointGrid`.

Using `g.ax_marg_y.set_axis_off()` I was able to hide it.
However, like you can see in the picture below, it still takes space when saving the figure using `plt.savefig(file, bbox_inches='tight')`.

[image: Plot]

Is it perhaps possible to **change the size** of the y-marginal plot? Then I could just make it very small.

Just to clarify, this is what happens if I don't use `set_axis_off()`:
[image]

Thanks in advance.

### My code

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

data = np.random.randn(50, 2)
data2 = np.random.randn(50, 2) + np.array([1, 0])

g = sns.JointGrid(space=0)
g.fig.set_facecolor("red")

sns.kdeplot(x=data[:, 0], linewidth=1.5, ax=g.ax_marg_x, fill=True)
sns.kdeplot(x=data2[:, 0], linewidth=1.5, ax=g.ax_marg_x, fill=True)
g.ax_marg_y.set_axis_off()

g.ax_joint.scatter(data[:, 0], y=data[:, 1], marker='D', s=30, label="A")
g.ax_joint.scatter(data2[:, 0], y=data2[:, 1], marker='*', s=80, label="B")

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems removing the axes `g.ax_marg_y.remove()` solves the problem for saving the plot.  But it doesn't seem to change the layout when displaying on the screen.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

data = np.random.randn(50, 2)
data2 = np.random.randn(50, 2) + np.array([1, 0])

g = sns.JointGrid(space=0)
g.fig.set_facecolor("red")

sns.kdeplot(x=data[:, 0], linewidth=1.5, ax=g.ax_marg_x, fill=True)
sns.kdeplot(x=data2[:, 0], linewidth=1.5, ax=g.ax_marg_x, fill=True)
g.ax_marg_y.set_axis_off()
g.ax_marg_y.remove()

g.ax_joint.scatter(data[:, 0], y=data[:, 1], marker='D', s=30, label="A")
g.ax_joint.scatter(data2[:, 0], y=data2[:, 1], marker='*', s=80, label="B")

g.savefig('joint_grid_without_marg_y.png' , bbox_inches='tight')

# plt.tight_layout()
# plt.show()
```

[image: joint grid without marg y]

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't change the layout when displaying on the screen"? It looks exactly like in the image you uploaded on my jupyter notebook.

Comment: So, in the notebook the figsize gets adapted, but not in my PyCharm environment.

Comment: Thanks!
If someone is interested in getting the right border of the plot back: `g.ax_joint.patch.set_edgecolor('black')  
g.ax_joint.patch.set_linewidth('1') `

Comment: The inline backend in the notebook saves figures with `bbox_inches="tight"`; you need to specify that elsewhere.